# Control the clickable area of a link

Tags: css

As you can see below I have a set of links quite close together and the clickable area of the links overlap:

[image: My link is too big]

I've tried playing with the padding and margin to no avail. How to I reduce the overlap?

Comment: Have you tried [`line-height`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/line-height)?

Comment: Yep, and height as well.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your situation and isn't always possible, but if you could manage to get the links to be `display: block`, `display: inline-block` or `position: absolute`, you would be able to explicitly set their width and height.